# Variable width & height of UICollectionViewCell using AutoLayout with Storyboard (without XIB)

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, autolayout, storyboard, height

Here is an design issue in the app that uses AutoLayout, UICollectionView and UICollectionViewCell that has automatically resizable width & height depending on AutoLayout constraints and its content (some text).

It is a UITableView list like, with each cell that has it's own width & height calculated separately for each row dependant on its content. It is more like iOS Messages build in app (or WhatsUp).

It is obvious that app should make use of `func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize`.

Issue is that within that method, app cannot call `func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell` nor `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(identifier: String, forIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> AnyObject` to instantiate cell, populate it with specific content and calculate its width & height. Trying to do that will result in an indefinite recursion calls or some other type of app crash (at least in iOS 8.3).

The closest way to fix this situation seems to copy definition of the cell into view hierarchy to let Auto-layout resize "cell" automatically (like cell to have the same width as parent collection view), so app can configure cell with specific content and calculate its size. This should definitely not be the only way to fix it because of duplicated resources.

All of that is connected with setting UILabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth to some value that should be Auto-Layout controllable (not hardcoded) that could depend on screen width & height or at least setup by Auto-layout constraint definition, so app can get multiline UILabel intrinsic size  calculated.

I would not like to instantiate cells from XIB file since Storyboards should be today's industry standard and I would like to have as less intervention in code.

EDIT:

The basic code that cannot be run is listed bellow. So only instantiating variable cellProbe (not used) crashes the app. Without that call, app runs smoothly.

```
var onceToken: dispatch_once_t = 0

class ViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

        dispatch_once(&onceToken) {

            let cellProbe = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("first", forIndexPath: NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)) as! UICollectionViewCell
        }

        return CGSize(width: 200,height: 50)
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("first", forIndexPath: NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)) as! UICollectionViewCell

        return cell
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are using constraints, you don't need to set a size per cell. So you should remove your delegate method `func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize`

Instead you need to set a size in `estimatedItemSize` by setting this to a value other than `CGSizeZero` you are telling the layout that you don't know the exact size yet. The layout will then ask each cell for it's size and it should be calculated when it's required.

```
let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
layout.estimatedItemSize = someReasonableEstimatedSize()
```

Comment: `preferredLayoutAttributesFittingAttributes(_ layoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes!` is nice, but problem is that I do not know actually cell's size. I need to have cell instance so I can populate it with content to know exact size of the cell. It is something like iMessage on iOS where every message has its own height based on content.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not understanding the problem then. You have your cell instance, and yes you should have populated it with content. You shouldn't normally need to override `preferredLayoutAttributesFittingAttributes(_ layoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes!` The default implementation will adjust the size, you would only override it to adjust other attributes. My only guess at this point is maybe you are using subviews that don't have an intrinsitContentSize e.g. if you use a UITextView rather than UILabel.

Comment: I just read through your original question again and see that you are trying to get a cell that you can populate to calculate the size. That's fine but you don't create it with either method you mentioned. Instead just create it like you would any other view. In fact you could just move all your cell code into a regular UIView subclass and set that subclass as the content view of the cell. Then you are just dealing with a view and should be able to set it's content and get its size. However, you shouldn't need to do any of that with self sizing cells - it's what we did before iOS 7 though.

Comment: Actually, I use UILabel as size-driving (intrinsitContentSize) view and I am capable of calculating overall UICollectionViewCell's size when it has right content setup.

Comment: Regarding your latest comment, it would be right if I would build up cells in a code or have its definition somehow external, like in separate NIB or template cell in view hierarchy. But, I have app design defined entirely in one Storyboard and I expected it is possible to have cel's definition in UICollectionView cell prototypes. However, it seems like it is not possible to have it this way and still make cell's height calculation based on variable content...

Comment: ...so, I ended up with my existing scenario where I have template cells attached to the UIView hierarchy  as a regular cells, but not visible, that I use for estimating cell's height.

Comment: Right. As I said, that is a method that can work and that was the normal way before auto sizing cells. However, it should no longer be required. If you are overriding default behavior then you may need to do this method. Otherwise, assuming you have correctly set up constraints, set `estimatedItemSize` and not `itemSize` then it should work fine.

Comment: I see. And what would be recommended place to fill in content specific to each cell so UIKit could calculate cell's size for each cell differently, when using `estimatedItemSize `?

Comment: Just set up your cells as you normally would in `func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell`

Comment: I guess you are right. Just using `estimatedItemSize` and `collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell` does automatic cell resizing, even height for multi-line UILabel so I am awarding you for right answer. But it is strange that in even basic setup UICollectionView does not well with `estimatedItemSize` because it crashes when trying to scroll list. I have sample app on Dropbox:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/x2uucjp504yowta/Collection-View-test.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 2):

Just like when dynamically size Table View Cell height using Auto Layout you don't need call

`func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`

in

`optional func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat`

the proper way is create a local static cell for height calculation like a class method of the custom cell

```
+ (CGFloat)cellHeightForContent:(id)content tableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    static CustomCell *cell;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:[CustomCell cellIdentifier]];
    });

    Item *item = (Item *)content;
    configureBasicCell(cell, item);

    [cell setNeedsLayout];
    [cell layoutIfNeeded];
    CGSize size = [cell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize];
    return size.height + 1.0f; // Add 1.0f for the cell separator height
}
```

and I seriously doubt storyboard is some industry standard. xib is the best way to create custom cell like view including tableViewCell and CollectionViewCell

Comment: Thank you for answer. I like the way you did it by instantiating cell once probably very early in the view appearance. I tried to do similar but when I call it from within viewWillAppear(animated: Bool), I get crash and when I call it from viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) it is kind of too late since collection view already requested height of the cell but I do not have one at that particular time. Maybe it needs to be in some overloaded layoutSubviews() function call or do some trick by first letting collection view dummy size and then call reloadData() when app loads cell.

Comment: @CROLakiluk you don't need call it in viewwill(did)appear it's a class method. write your own `sizeForContent:` and call it in `sizeForItemAtIndexPaht`

Comment: appreciate your help, but in UICollectionView with flow layout this approach does not perform well. You may take a look at edited post...

Answer (score 2):

To calculate the `CollectionView` cell's size dynamically, just set the flow layout property to any arbitrary value:

```
 let flowLayout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
 flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
```